# Python how to join cross platform paths

Tags: python, path, os.path

If I have a json directory structure that lists paths in mac format ()i.e. 
`"/0000_test/video.mp4"` and I want to join it with `c:\\` the mac format, is there a way to do this?

So on windows the path would be returned as `c:\\0000_test\video.mp4"`

I have tried `os.path.join to no avail`

Comment: Do you have a small example of the code you are using and is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath)

```
>>> os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:', '/0000_test/video.mp4'))
'C:\\0000_test\\video.mp4'
```

`normpath` will take care of normalizing the path in a platform specific manner.